# How to auto edit the first line content in text file using shell script

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Here is the file name: `SUMAAI011.A01`

Here is the file content and would like to rename the first line `01UMAGL011` to `01UMAKBO11`

```
01UMAGL011
0201
0306222021
041063563563
051066675663
063147000
07000
```

Comment: Will `01UMAGL011` appear elsewhere in the file? If not `sed -e 's/

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed`, the stream editor. Read `man sed`.

```
sed -e '1s/01UMAGL011/01UMAKBO11' SUMMAI011.A01
```

In your question your replacement strings ends in "`O11`" should it be "`011`"?

Comment: The `-e` doesn't really make a difference here. It does seem, however, the OP is looking for in-place substitution, so it'd probably make more sense to let `-i` take its place.